# Warning: require_once(): open_basedir restriction in effect

Tags: php, path

I got this error i tried to change permission for all files and folders nothing happen i tried to use dirname(**FILE**) but nothing happen is there anyone can help me ???

```
Warning: require_once(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/zadmin/public_html/XXXXXXXX/loader.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/zadmin/public_html/XXXXXXXXXXXX/htdocs:/var/zpanel/temp/) in /home/zadmin/public_html/XXXXXXXXXXXXXX/htdocs/loader.php on line 10

Warning: require_once(/home/zadmin/public_html/XXXXXXXXXX/loader.php): failed to open stream: Operation not permitted in /home/zadmin/public_html/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/htdocs/loader.php on line 10

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/zadmin/public_html/XXXXXXXXXXXXXX/loader.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /home/zadmin/public_html/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/htdocs/loader.php on line 10
```

Comment: Its `dirname(__FILE__);`

Comment: yes i use this `require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/loader.php');`

Comment: Mine was not the solution, so deleted the answer. I thought your htdocs is the root. Look at Finwe's answer. Notice the path without `htdocs`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/php-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only access to files set in your [`open_basedir`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) directive, which are `/home/zadmin/public_html/XXXXXXXXXXXX/htdocs` and `/var/zpanel/temp/`.

If you need to load files directly from `/home/zadmin/public_html/XXXXXXXXXXXX`, set your `open_basedir` directive accordingly or contact your hosting provider to set it for you.

Comment: I try make something like this  `php_admin_value open_basedir "/home/zadmin/public_html/XXXXXXXXXXX/htdocs:/var/zpanel/temp/"`

Comment: @Tetsh You have to remove `htdocs` from the path if you want it to work: `php_admin_value open_basedir "/home/zadmin/public_html/XXXXXXXXXXX/:/var/zpanel/tem‌​p/"`

Comment: thank you it's working but i got this warning `touch(): Utime failed: Permission denied`

Comment: @Tetsh Those are file permission problems, different matter entirely. Make sure you have write permissions for files the touch is being called on.